# Get file names from server path directory using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to pick up image file names only from windows server path using javascript

For Example: "\sampelDirectory\imageFolder"

Comment: It doesn't work with pure JavaScript. You also need php.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API